# Как объединить неск слайдеров

Tags: javascript

Всем доброго!

На сайте имеется около 10 слайдеров. В js пока новичок, подскажите, как их объединить вместе, а не писать каждому одно и тоже.

Значит слайдеры с классом showcase, showcase2 .....
Код у всех один:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".showcase").awShowcase(
    {
        content_width:          410,
        content_height:         348,
        hundred_percent:        false,
        auto:                   true,
        interval:               3000,
        continuous:             true,
        loading:                true,
        tooltip_width:          200,
        tooltip_icon_width:     32
    });
});
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".showcase2").awShowcase(
    {
        content_width:          410,
        content_height:         348,
        hundred_percent:        false,
        auto:                   true,
        interval:               3000,
        continuous:             true,
        loading:                true,
        tooltip_width:          200,
        tooltip_icon_width:     32
       });
});
</script>
```

Comment: А вы через скрипты хотите их как-то объединить? Не проще это сделать в html?

Comment: Как их через html объединю, если у каждого разное содержание. Каждому одни и те же параметры задаются в скрипте, вот как правильно - что не  каждому писать `$(document).ready(function() $(".showcase").awShowcase, $(document).ready(function() $(".showcase2").awShowcase`, а все вместе через запятую, что ли? Просто синтаксис скрипта у меня вообще на нуле.

Comment: Значит тема немного не соотвествует содержимому у вас, вам нужно объединить скрипты, а не слайдеры, и да, можно попробовать вызвать через запятую:

`$(".showcase, .showcase2, .showcase3").awShowcase(..`

Comment: Неа, не работает через запятую.